# read.table() not working with simple input .txt file

Tags: r, read.table

I have a simple .txt file formatted as follows:

```
V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6
1   Lepirudin           DB00001 1   BE0000048   Prothrombin                                               
2   Cetuximab           DB00002 1   BE0000767   Epidermal growth factor receptor                          
2   Cetuximab           DB00002 2   BE0000901   Low affinity immunoglobulin gamma Fc region
```

I want to read in the file and then process the content. However, when I just try to read in this file above using `read.table()`, I get the following error messages:

```
OutputFileContent <- read.table("Data.txt",header=FALSE)
```

> OutputFileContent <- read.table("Data.txt",header=FALSE)
>       Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  :
>         line 1 did not have 13 elements

```
OutputFileContent <- read.table("Data.txt",header=TRUE)
```

> OutputFileContent <- read.table("Data.txt",header=TRUE)
>       Error in read.table("EdgeList_Experiment.txt", header = TRUE) :
>         more columns than column names

... even though there are 6 columns and 6 column names...

Can anyone suggest why even this seemingly simple function call is failing, when the input file is a simple, small .txt file? Thanks in advance for your insights.

Comment: OutputFileContent <- read.table("Data.txt",header=TRUE, sep="\t" ,quote="")

Comment: It fails because the spaces in the last column are being interpreted as field separators. To fix this we need to know more about the format of your file. If it is fixed width format consider using read.fwf. If not then consider using readLines and parsing the file within R. Alternatively if the file is very large you can fix this outside R using awk to replace the field separators with tabs or commas.

Answer (score 1):

1) remove spaces between the columns in the .txt file. Use Tap between the columns to separate as below.

```
V1  V2  V3  V4  V5  V6
1   Lepirudin   DB00001 1   BE0000048   Prothrombin
2   Cetuximab   DB00002 1   BE0000767   Epidermal growth factor receptor
2   Cetuximab   DB00002 2   BE0000901   Low affinity immunoglobulin gamma Fc region
```

2) OutputFileContent <- read.table("ttt.txt",header=TRUE, sep ='\t')

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your helpful suggestions, all.

To address orizon's question, the file was generated using the following:

`write.fwf(CompositeMatrix,file="Data.txt",sep="\t", quote=F, rownames=F, colnames=F)`

Regarding S Rivero's suggestion to use:
OutputFileContent <- read.table("Data.txt",header=TRUE, sep="\t" ,quote="")

... this works well, except that for some reason "X1" is inserted twice in the first row of content.

Regarding JKim's suggestion to remove the spaces between the columns in the text file and use the suggested function call, this worked, except that there is one instance of X1 inserted in the first row of values, and the entire first line is shifted significantly rightward and has mistaken content as follows:

```
X1.Lepirudin...........DB00001.1..BE0000048.Prothrombin
```

I appreciate your input, and will play around with this further to try to resolve these remaining issues.

Comment: Did you succeed?